# implementing and testing thread_create function

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm very new in C and Linux and English is not my mother language. Sorry in advance.

I'm working on a school project which is implementing thread api and I made the thread_create() function using clone(). 
The problem is that when I call `thread_create(&tid1, NULL, (void *)Testcase1, 0);` ,
it creates a new thread but TestCase1 also includes thread_create and it doesn't seem create another thread. Let me explain with my code below:

```
int foo(void* arg){
    printf("Hii");
    return 0;
}
int     thread_create(thread_t *thread, thread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)
{
    void* stack;

    stack= malloc( STACK_SIZE );
    pid_t pid;

    if( stack==0)
    {
        perror( "malloc : could not allocate stack" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    pid = clone( &foo ,( char* )stack+STACK_SIZE,SIGCHLD|CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES,0 );
    if(pid == -1)
    {
        perror("clone");
        exit(2);
    }
    kill(pid, SIGSTOP);

    Thread* newTCB = (Thread*)malloc(sizeof(Thread));
    newTCB->stackSize = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    newTCB->pid = pid;
    newTCB->status = THREAD_STATUS_READY;

    rEnqueue(newTCB);
    rPrintqueue();

    free(stack);
    printf("Child thread returned and stack freed.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my test code below:

```
    thread_create(&tid1, NULL, (void*)TestCase1, 0);
```

TestCase1() below:

```
int Tc1ThreadProc(int param)
{
    int tid = 0;
    int count = 0;

    tid = thread_self();

    count = 3;
    while (count > 0)
    {
        /* sleep for 1 seconds */
        sleep(2);
        printf("Tc1ThreadProc: my thread id (%d), arg is (%d)\n", tid, param);
        count--;
    }
}
void TestCase1(void)
{
    thread_t tid[TOTAL_THREAD_NUM];

    thread_create(&tid[0], NULL, (void*)Tc1ThreadProc, (int*)1);
    thread_create(&tid[1], NULL, (void*)Tc1ThreadProc, (int*)2);
    thread_create(&tid[2], NULL, (void*)Tc1ThreadProc, (int*)3);

    while(1){}

    return ;
}
```

it's supposed to print `"Tc1ThreadProc: my thread id (%d), arg is (%d)\n"` 3 times but it prints only `"Hii"` which is because of the call to `foo()`.
How do I fix this?

Comment: A couple of problems: Your `thread_create` function wants a pointer *to a pointer* to a function; Your thread function `Tc1ThreadProc` takes an `int` as argument, when `sizeof(int)` might be different from `sizeof(void*)` leading to *undefined behavior; Your `thread_create` function is hardcoded to invoke `foo` and not the function you pass to it; You don't initialize the `thread` argument; And lastly your free the stack in the creation function, so the thread have no stack.

Comment: then which function do I need to call instead of foo()? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: For the `clone` call you should pass the pointer to the function passed to `thread_create`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't get it. What does that 'the pointer to the function passed to thread_create' ?

Comment: You should pass the `thread_routine` variable to the `clone` call. And please disregard the first "problem" in my first comment, I misread the code. The rest are still valid though.

Comment: Oh and another problem: Your thread functions *must* return a `void*` value. Otherwise you will have *undefined behavior*. And that you need to cast the thread function argument you pass to `thread_create` is a sign that you're doing something you should not be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass pointer to function "TestCase1" as argument to "thread_create", but inside "thread_create" you don't use it at all:

```
thread_create(&tid1, NULL, (void*)TestCase1, 0);
```

You're calling "clone" syscall only with pointer to "foo" function.
From inside "thread_create" your "TestCase1" pointer is named "start_routine", so you need to call similar "clone" syscall, but instead pointer to "foo" you should pass pointer to "TestCase1". Something like that:

```
pid = clone( start_routine, (char*) stack + STACK_SIZE, SIGCHLD | CLONE_VM | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES, 0);
```

Comment: Completely understood! Thanks a lot!

Comment: And you should free stack memory of the child process when it finishes, usually at SIGCHLD routine in parent process.

Comment: Then should I free stack memory at the end of thread_create()?

Comment: I don't get the meaning of "SIGCHLD routine in parent process"

Comment: No you shouldn't, because you don't know how long the child process / thread will leave. So when the child process finish his job and exit, the OS will signal parent process with SIGCHLD. (From clone manual man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html). 
To add signal handler you have to define function:
void SigChildHandler(int nSignal)
{
}

and call:
"signal(SIGCLD, SigChildHandler);" 
For example from main function on your parent process.